# Nativescript RadSideDrawer undefined

Tags: android, ios, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I have a problem with implementing shared SideDrawer. I was following this article https://www.nativescript.org/blog/a-deep-dive-into-telerik-ui-for-nativescripts-sidedrawer

Main page XML:

```
<Page 
  xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" 
  xmlns:sd="nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer" loaded="pageLoaded">
  <Page.actionBar>
    <ActionBar class="action-bar" title="Manu">
      <android>
        <NavigationButton icon="res://ic_menu" tap="toggleDrawer" />
      </android>
      <ios>
        <ActionItem icon="res://ic_menu" ios.position="left" tap="toggleDrawer" />
      </ios>
    </ActionBar>
  </Page.actionBar>
  <sd:RadSideDrawer id="sideDrawer">
    <sd:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent 
      xmlns:Drawer="Views/SideDrawerView">
      <Drawer:SideDrawerView />
    </sd:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>
  </sd:RadSideDrawer>
  <StackLayout>
    <Label text="{{ sync }}" />
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Main page codebehind:

```
import { EventData } from 'data/observable';
import { Page } from 'ui/page';
import { MainViewModel } from '../../ViewModels/MainViewModel';

let frameModule = require("ui/frame");
let view = require("ui/core/view");
let page: Page;

export function pageLoaded(args: EventData) {
    page = <Page>args.object;
    page.bindingContext = new MainViewModel();    
}

export function toggleDrawer () {
    let drawer: any = view.getViewById(page, "sideDrawer");
    drawer.toggleDrawerState();
};
```

SideDrawer XML:

```
<StackLayout class="sidedrawer-left" loaded="drawerViewLoaded">
    <StackLayout class="sidedrawer-header">
        <Label text="Hello RadSideDrawer!" class="sidedrawer-header-brand" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout class="sidedrawer-content">
        <Label text="QrScanner" class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" tap="qrScan" />
        <Label text="New Item" class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" tap="nItem" />
        <Label text="Edit Item" class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" tap="eItem" />
        <Label text="Users" class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" tap="openUsers" />
        <Label text="Map" class="sidedrawer-list-item-text" tap="map" />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

So, when I actually tap and call toggleDrawer function

```
export function toggleDrawer () {
    let drawer: any = view.getViewById(page, "sideDrawer");
    drawer.toggleDrawerState();
};
```

it says drawer is undefined. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way :) as you have tap event you can get tap event data inside `toggleDrawer` and from `args` get tapped object's `page` from where you can access `sideDrawer` controlling or using `frameModule`'s `topmost()` function

```
export function toggleDrawer (args: EventData) {
    //this way
    let page = <Page>(<any>args.object).page;
    //or this way
    let page = frameModule.topmost();
    //at last get drawer content at page
    let drawer: any = page.getViewById("sideDrawer");
    drawer.toggleDrawerState();
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I resolved the issue. Read the comment below.

Comment: @Xoyce which comment ? or where ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by declaring custom component inside Page element, instead sd:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent.

```
<Page 
  xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" 
  xmlns:sd="nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer" 
  xmlns:Drawer="Views/SideDrawerView" loaded="pageLoaded">
```